# how to configue my apache2 webserver?

Tags: android

Am trying to develope an android application that send images to my server for processing reasons ,what is the best way to configure it inorder to recieve data from android users(am using http req)
Thanks

Comment: I think you'll have to get much more specific to get useful answers.  What have you tried and how didn't it work?

Comment: I should also add that if it is just an apache configuration question, then perhaps one of the other stack exchange sites might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache is simply a webserver. Generally when you send images they are sent as POST data. This means you'll need to make sure that Apache can handle the sizes of the images that are sent to it. The directive LimitRequestBody controls this limit for Apache. It's set to '0' by default. This means it wont limit the POST body size.

The next thing you need is have a server side script take care of the processing, storage and response to the client. You may use ruby (Rails), PHP, Java to accomplish this. Each framework has default limits. For instance PHP has 'upload_max_filesize' directive which needs to be set if you expect the images beyond the default 2MB. This is set in the php.ini.